# response.jsonPath() has square brackets around the element, how do I retrieve the string value? Rest Assured

Tags: java, testing, httpresponse, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have an HTTP response body that looks that this when I make a GET request:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "1111",
    "type": "Sale",
    "name": "MyNameTest",
    "shortDescription": "Sale a"
  }
]
```

When I try to assert the results with "Rest Assured", the name value is always wrapped in square brackets [].

```
    final String returnedAttributeValue = response.jsonPath().getString("name");
    Assert.assertEquals(returnedAttributeValue, "MyNameTest");
```

So the test fails with Expected "MyNameTest", but was "[MyNameTest]"

Can any one tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing values within an array, so use `name[n]`

```
final String returnedAttributeValue = response.jsonPath().getString("name[0]");
Assert.assertEquals(returnedAttributeValue, "MyNameTest");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$[0].name`?

Comment: In `Rest Assured` JSON Path syntax uses `Groovy's GPath` notation and is not to be confused with `Jayway's JsonPath` syntax

Comment: Aha. An unfortunate name collision.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution for checking the content of an array, you could use `org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains`:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;

response
  .andExpect(jsonPath("$name", contains("MyNameTest")));
```